# Unable to execute RPC, reason? DBConnection?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I get the following error-message if I run my GAE Application. I can not figure out, what the problem is. MySQL driver is the newest. Reconfigured the DBConnection.

Versions:
App-Engine: 1.9.34
GWT: 2.7.0
Java: 1.8

> Mai 18, 2017 12:15:27 PM
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
>   SCHWERWIEGEND: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while
>   dispatching incoming RPC call
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method
>   'public abstract java.util.ArrayList
>   de.pitchMen.shared.PitchMenAdmin.getMarketplaces() throws
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Excuse me for this short message. Ask me, if you need more informations.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is in your own code, but because it is a RuntimeException or Error, it is not caught by RPC, and propagated in a confusing way.

Check your `public abstract java.util.ArrayList de.pitchMen.shared.PitchMenAdmin.getMarketplaces() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` method, fix it, and the error should be gone.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. To avoid the error, it was the simplest way to disable the local Google App Engine tool. After disabling, everything works fine.